# DIV com divisão de cores

Tags: html, css

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer para que minha div fique com essa divisão de cores:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisará usar *CSS* `linear-gradient`.

### O linear-gradient

`linear-gradient` é uma funcionalidade das CSS3 para criar degrades entre 2 ou mais cores em linha.

Sendo assim você vai precisar usar o seguinte código para gerar este background na sua `div`

```css
.gradientbg{
    background: #f6f5f4;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #f6f5f4 0%, #f6f5f4 50%, #ffffff 51%, #ffffff 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%,#f6f5f4), color-stop(50%,#f6f5f4), color-stop(51%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#ffffff));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #f6f5f4 0%,#f6f5f4 50%,#ffffff 51%,#ffffff 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, #f6f5f4 0%,#f6f5f4 50%,#ffffff 51%,#ffffff 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, #f6f5f4 0%,#f6f5f4 50%,#ffffff 51%,#ffffff 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #f6f5f4 0%,#f6f5f4 50%,#ffffff 51%,#ffffff 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f6f5f4', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=1 );
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="gradientbg"></div>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado!!

Comment: Erlon, preciso aumentar o degrade do cinza um pouco mais para a direita, como posso fazer?

Comment: Use o [**Colorzilla**](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/), este aplicativo vai te ajudar muito a criar os efeitos visuais *css* que você precisar